# one of our top sellers

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Apple and airplane prints are two different designs of prints.

---

> 1. The apple and airplane prints are still one of our **top sellers**

After a search, I understand it is correct to use plural. For e.g. ***one of the bags***, ***one of the baskets***, ***one of the leading companies***.

Will that rule still be applicable if is to use with more than one item like in sentence 1?

---

> 2. The apple and airplane print are still one of our **top sellers**

In sentence 2, If I were to use *print* instead of *prints*, does it convey the same category and quantity as in sentence 1?

---

> 3. The apple prints is/are still one of our top sellers

In sentence 3, is using *is* acceptable here if I would like to convey a category instead of the number of prints?

---

> 4. Apple and airplane prints are still one of our top sellers.

In sentence 4, does it convey that apple and airplane print belongs to the same type of printing category but two different designs?

Comment: Consider version zero:  "The apple and airplane prints are *two* of your top sellers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are imagining that "one of our top sellers" is an idiom. Or, that "one of ___" is.  In other words, it's a fixed phrase which has a special meaning and shouldn't be modified.

If so, that's not exactly true. The sentence ought to make sense when intepreted literally.

Thus, you shouldn't say "one", when at the beginning of the question you have already clarified "Apple and airplane prints are **two** different designs of prints."

Alternatives are:

> The apple and airplane prints are *two* of our top sellers.

or

> The apple and airplane prints are *among* our top sellers.

Comment: It's probably confusing because you could say "The airplane prints are one of our top sellers" - there are multiple prints, but only one type of print, so you can use a plural "are" but still say "one", because the "one" means "one of our top selling *types* of print" - you're counting types, not prints.  But if you have multiple prints belonging to *two* types, you have *two* types that are "two of our top sellers".

Comment: @Sam you hit the nail on the head. At the back of my mind, I assumed `one of the __` is an idiom and a fixed phrase. Thanks!

Comment: @A.B. Thanks for explaining that in a way that is easily understandable! It is very helpful for my learning.